# JPA join using single field of a composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two table and one of them (Book) has a Composite key. Another table Author has a reference to the bId column from Book. Is it possible to join this in JPA ?

```
@Embeddable
public class T1Id implements Serializable {

private String bId;
private String name;
private String country;
}
```

T1 - Book

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "book")
public class Book implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private T1Id id;

@OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "book")
private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();
}
```

T2 - Author

```
Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author implements Serializable {

private String bId;

private String address;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bId", referencedColumnName="bId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Book book;
}
```

If I add other columns from Books in the Join criteria, it gives me an error, as the Address Entity doesnt have those column. And if I try to join using above approach, it errors out saying that the number of columns is wrong

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering Book from Author has the wrong number of column. should be 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `referencedColumnName="bId"` to specify the column

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bId", referencedColumnName="bId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Book book;
```

or use @MapsId

```
@MapsId("bId")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Book book;
```

Comment: adding referencedColumnName doesnt help. I still get the same Error. The use case here is I want to join based of one field of the Composite Key. 
Is it possible through JPA to do a join use single field of a multi field Composite Key ?

Comment: It's working like that. In database column name is bId ?